# How to add on a site page a button allowing to upload a folder (and not files individually) to a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload, power-automate, button

I am designing a SharePoint site for a team so we can share documentation with external users. I wish to add a button on the homepage for the colleagues who will upload documentation with me. Once the upload is done, a flow with power automate analyze the information and parse it in several document libraries - and this part is OK for the moment. I would just need to add this button, so I am sure the folder they upload goes to right library. I have done a lot of research on the topic, but cannot find any help - especially since I want to upload a folder and not files.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below solution meets your requirement.

- Add an app named **File Uploader by Virto** from SharePoint Store to your SharePoint site.
  [image]
- Find it in Site Contents library and click it to run the app.
  [image]
- Cpoy the url of upcoming page.
  [image]
- Add a Button web part on your home page, edit the web part and paste the url you copied above into Link.

[image]

Test on my end.
[image]

Hope this may help.